# Increment hash name with counter or passed parameter

Tags: ruby, variables, hash

I'm trying to create a method which will name the hash accordingly when called and given a parameter.

```
def message_info(number)

        @browser.link(:data_class => 'home.conv.message.message_info').click
        messageid = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.client_id').text
        sender = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.sender_name').text
        senderusername = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.sender_user_name').text
        recipient = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.recipient_name').text
        recipientusername = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.recipient_user_name').text
        created = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.created').text
        status = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.status').text
        ttl = @browser.span(:data_class, 'home.conv.view_message_info.ttl').text

        message_info_hash + number = {

          'Message ID' => "#{messageid}",
          'Sender Name' => "#{sender}",
          'Sender Username' => "#{senderusername}",
          'Recipient name' => "#{recipient}",
          'Recipient Username' => "#{recipientusername}",
          'Created' => "#{created}",
          'Status' => "#{status}",
          'TTL' => "#{ttl}"

        }

      end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to set named local variables (which would accomplish nothing) store your message info in a hash, and use `number` as a key into it.

```
def initialize
  @message_info = {}
end 

def message_info(number)
  # ...
  @message_info[number] = { ... }
end
```

You also don't need to interpolate the values into strings in order to stringify them. Rather than:

```
'Message ID' => "#{messageid}"
```

Use:

```
'Message ID' => messageid.to_s
```